# Software for simulating (partial) differential equations

Tags: partial-differential-equations, math-software

I am looking for a way of getting some intuition for some Convection Diffusion Equation. I would like to play around with it, simulate it, change its IC/BCs, having some interactive graphs and stuff.

Do you know of any free software that does the job? Thank you!

Comment: OpenFOAM might also be a tool. But I am not sure, if this might be too begin with.

Comment: @macydanim: Could you form that into an answer? Thank you!

Comment: Done, but I just noticed that you asked this question two years ago, sorry.

Comment: @macydanim - But I am still interested :-) Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Dynare](http://www.dynare.org/) on top of [Octave](http://www.gnu.org/software/octave/) should do the Trick.

Answer (score 1):

OpenFOAM might also be a tool. But I am not sure, if this might be too difficult to begin with.

You can find it on their [homepage](http://www.openfoam.com/).
A quick google search offered this tutorial, [see slide 17ff](http://cfd.iut.ac.ir/files/Tutorial,%20University%20of%20California,%20San%20Diego%20.pdf), where the convection-diffusion equation is solved. But I personally would start with the OpenFOAM [tutorial](http://www.openfoam.org/docs/user/tutorials.php).